# White Screen - App content failed to load after launch released iOS app

Tags: arp, nt

I installed my application play store seamlessly. However, when I tried to install the App Store, the application was rejected and I received the following message.
Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 12.3.1 on Wi-Fi.

When we launched the app, app displayed a splash screen and no further action occurred in the app during the review.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

Resources

For information about testing your app and preparing it for review, please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.

For a networking overview, please review About Networking.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

When I write flutter doctor there is no problem.
I tried the application on the real device again no problem.
But the app store made such a turn. Does anyone know the reason or are having the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
https://www.flutterforum.org/d/97-white-screen-app-content-failed-to-load-after-launch-released-ios-app
Thank you!

It took me three days. But solved ...

Comment: same problem now i repeated those steps but the same when i run the release version, it appears white screen.

Comment: I followed the steps and still getting rejected with same white screenshot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i faced same problem with android version of flutter app, when testers install app from google play, the white screen appear, but when test direct apk on device the app not installed appear.
That problem happen after i update android sdk tool to version 30

**after long search, i solved the problem with step:**

- in dependences in android\build.gradle  downgrade gradle from 4.0.0 to 3.5.0 as the default value new flutter app determined
- in app\build.gradle downgrade compileSdkVersion to 29 and so targetSdkVersion to 29 too
- run the flutter clean command

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you followed the developer guidelines carefully here at this link:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive

Steps to generate ipa:

1. Execute the following command `flutter build ios --release`
2. To ensure that Xcode refreshes the release mode configuration, close and re-open your Xcode workspace. For Xcode 8.3 and later, this step is not required. Finally Select `Product > Archive` to produce a build archive.

Hope this helps :)